# how to convert cell array content to ordinal values?

Tags: matlab, ordinal

guys, i want to convert this cell array into ordinal values as shown in the screenshot
[image]

[image]

```
    catnames = { 'stage i';  'stage ia'; 'stage ii'; 'stage iia'; 'stage iib'; 'stage iic'; 'stage iii'; 'stage iiia';'stage iiib'; 'stage iiic'; 'stage iv'; 'stage iva'; 'stage ivb'};
valueset={1;2;3;4};
for i=1:217
    B = categorical(Ystg{i}(2),catnames,valueset,'Ordinal',true);
end
```

I have used this code but doesn't work and show this error: Error using categorical
Creating an instance of the Abstract class 'categorical' is not
allowed.

Comment: for example in case of stage iiic i want to convert it to 3

Answer (score 0):

```
    for i=1:217
    if strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage i') || strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage ia')
        Stage(i,1)  = 1;
    else if strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage ii') || strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iia')|| strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iib')|| strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iic')
            Stage(i,1) = 2;
        else if strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iii') || strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iiia')|| strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iiib')|| strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iiic')
                Stage(i,1)  = 3;
            else if strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iv') || strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage iva')|| strcmpi(Ystg{i}(2),'stage ivb')
                    Stage(i,1) = 4;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```